# Updating action with += does not chain operations after stored in collection or variable

Tags: c#, collections, delegates, action

I am trying to store Actions in a collection like so:

```
List<Action> localActionList = new List<Action>();
localActionList.Add(anotherObject.action1);
localActionList.Add(anotherObject.action2);
```

Later, I am adding a local listener to this Action like this:

```
actionList[0] += LocalListenerMethod;
```

When `anotherObject.action1` is invoked, `LocalListenerMethod` does not fire. I've come to the point where I suspect this has something to do with delegate immutability, but I can't figure how to do what I need to do (iterate through a list of Actions, assigning them to a local listener, getting called when the original Action is invoked in the original class). Note, I have no problem getting the listeners to fire when simply assigning to the original Action.

Simpler sample (without arrays):

```
Action x = ()=> Console.WriteLine("a");
Action y = x;
x += ()=> Console.WriteLine("b");
x(); // prints "ab"
y(); // prints "a"
```

Comment: It looks like what you want are `event`s.

Comment: Let's write another program:  `string  x = "a"; string y = x; x += "b"; Console.WriteLine(x); Console.WriteLine(y);`  What do you expect? Do you expect a different result in your version of the program that uses delegates?

Comment: @EricLippert I feel like I'm falling into a trap, but I would since a delegate is a reference type and an int is a value type. I'd equate it more to `var x = new MyType() { prop1 = 5 }; var y = x; x.prop1 += 1;` (MyType is a class) in which case `x.prop1` and `y.prop1` would both be 6. Obviously I'm wrong though. :)

Comment: What do reference type vs value types have to do with it? Would you expect different behaviour from strings? I've changed my comment to use strings instead of ints. Do you expect things will change?

Comment: And the snarky tech guy award goes to Eric. How can I then keep a reference to the original action in a collection such that it will be called when the original is invoked? Events can't be referenced outside of the class they're declared in. I want to store a collection of delegates that belong to one object in another, and then iterate through those, assigning methods as necessary.

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve. But it looks like one of these solutions only the original author will understand, at least for a couple of days. Whatever it should do, I think that there must be a much simpler solution.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is this: 
1) Four different user inputs trigger the same behavior.
2) However, these must be in order. Input 2 should only trigger the behavior after input 1 has triggered it, and so on.
3) My thought was to have a collection of references to the input actions I'm listening for. I subscribe to the first delegate, and each time it is invoked, I move on to the next one. This way the behavior is always triggered in the order I've established in the collection.

Comment: 4) The input class is separate from the listening class, which would seem to preclude using events (the compiler complains that I can't add the event to my collection outside of the class it is declared in).

If there is a better way of tackling this, I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: _" If there is a better way of tackling this"_ -- that type of question is just way too broad. You haven't provided enough context nor constraints. There are countless different ways you might achieve what you're trying to do. The point here is an explanation for why the code you tried doesn't work. With that knowledge, you should on your own be able to devise a design that addresses the various goals and requirements you have. If you want help with that part, you need to post a new question, with a lot more context, including a good [mcve] showing _exactly_ what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

> When `anotherObject.action1` is invoked, `LocalListenerMethod` does not fire

That's because the value of `anotherObject.action1` never changed.

To elaborate on Eric's comments, consider:

```
string a = "A", b = "B";
List<string> list = new List<string>();

list.Add(a);
list.Add(b);
list[0] += "C";
```

While the element contained at index `0` of `list` will now have the value of "AC", that doesn't mean that the `string` value referenced by the variable `a` has changed. How could it? The `list` object has no knowledge of that variable. The variable `a` will still reference the string `"A"`.

The *value* in the variable was passed to the `Add()` method, but that involves simply retrieving that value from the variable and sending it to the method. The variable itself is just a temporary storage place that was holding that value until it was needed. The variable itself plays no part in anything that happens afterward.

Similarly, in your example, the statement

```
actionList[0] += LocalListenerMethod;
```

does change the value of the element at index `0` of `actionList`. But that has no effect whatsoever on the value of your original variable `anotherObject.action1`. The value of that variable remains exactly as it was before. Passing the *value* of that variable to the list's `Add()` method just copies the value (which is a reference to a delegate type instance) from the variable to the method's argument list, so the *value* can be passed. But the variable itself is not given to the list, nor does the list object have any way to modify the variable.

And to address this comment you made:

> I'd equate it more to `var x = new MyType() { prop1 = 5 }; var y = x; x.prop1 += 1;`

That's a *very* different scenario. That would be more like something like this:

```
MyType x = new MyType { prop1 = 5 };
List<MyType> list = new List<MyType>();

list.Add(x);
list[0].prop1 += 1;

// Here, x.prop1 will be equal to 6, as would list[0].prop1
```

Note that in that example, the code is *not* modifying the list element itself, but rather a class *member* of the object referenced by the list element. That is, the "variable" (i.e. "the thing that changes") in the expression `list[0].prop1 += 1` is the `prop1` property, and *not* the `list[0]` element, as it is in the first two examples above. In this third example, `list[0]` is being used just to get the object for the property `prop1`, and is not otherwise involved in the `+=` assignment.

By the way, Eric's comments are not snarky at all. He is asking you questions designed to narrow down precisely what it is that is confusing you about the scenario. He's trying to understand how much comprehension you have of other scenarios in C#, and whether and how he can use those other scenarios to help explain this one. It is possible that during this questioning, you might have discovered your misunderstanding yourself, but if not, the answers to those questions would have provided Eric a means to focus on exactly the thing he needs to focus on to reach a helpful response to you as efficiently as possible.

Asking questions is a skill that needs to be learned. You can improve your own question-asking skills by becoming less defensive about questions asked of *you* in the process of trying to answer your own question, and especially by recognizing classic educational techniques, time-tested and designed to make the question-and-answer most efficient.

Comment: I appreciate your thorough response, and what you're saying makes sense. The question I'm left with is how have a collection of delegate references that will in fact get fired when the original is invoked.

Comment: Re: snark. we're all aware of the value of questions in pedagogy. Just as this is a learned skill, so is written communication. Just because we're talking about tech doesn't justify an absence of basic conventions in communication--namely, tact

Comment: @Orbis: _"The question I'm left with is how have a collection of delegate references that will in fact get fired when the original is invoked"_ -- any way you like. There's not enough context in your question to know what approach would be best for you. One obvious solution would be to modify the original: `anotherObject.action1 += () => localActionList[0]();`. Another obvious solution would be to change the code that invokes `anotherObject.action1` so that it also invokes `localActionList[0]`.

Comment: @Orbis: ... Yet another solution would be to use a container type to hold `action1` and put that container in the `localActionList` instead of `Action` instances, and then when you want to modify it, you modify the value in the container (which will update it in both places, a la your `MyType` example). Sorry you didn't find my answer useful at all, never mind felt that it actually answer your direct question.

Comment: @Orbis: As for "snark" and "tact", you clearly haven't learned the skill of not taking the educational process personally. There _really_ was nothing _at all_ in Eric's comments that should have been taken as anything other than genuinely helpful. "Tact" should not mean dancing on the head of a pin just to allay a student's fragile ego. There's a big difference between avoiding truly insulting behavior, and coddling someone. It sounds like you really want the latter.

Comment: Appreciate the practical suggestions. You're right, I'm probably being unrealistic if I'm expecting people writing about tech online to set aside the faint air of petulance their comments nearly always seem to carry.